# Flutter: Place widget on top of the other with negative positioning

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to implement this `modalBottomSheet`

[image]

and I thought to use `Stack` with negative positioning

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
        return Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
            children: [
                Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 200,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Column(//here there will be the text)
                ),
                Positioned(
                    top: -20,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Palette.white,
                        radius: 38,
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data.image),
                            radius: 34,
                            backgroundColor: Palette.white),
                     ),
                 )]);
```

However this cuts the top part of the `CircleAvatar` picture (as I kind of expected).

Any idea on how to implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to change the clipBehavior to Clip.none on the Stack

```
Stack(
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my tricky implementation.

1. Set bottom sheet's background color to transparent.
2. Add top margin as avatar's half height to base Container.
3. Set base container's background color to white
4. Change the avatar's top position value to 0

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          show();
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  void show() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 200,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Alessandro Liparoti',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 25),
                      Text(
                        '4 games palyed',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  radius: 38,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/147/147144.png'),
                      radius: 34,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```